# I have a casting error (String to int)

Tags: java

A friend and I are making a simple game where it randomly picks one of those names and the user has to guess it until he/she gets it right. , but we are getting an error saying: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Adam Kovic". Can anyone please help?

```
package projectpackage;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectClass {
    public static void main(String eth[]) {

    int adam = Integer.valueOf("Adam Kovic");
    int bruce = Integer.valueOf("Bruce Greene");
    int joel = Integer.valueOf("Joel Ruben");
    int spoole = Integer.valueOf("Sean Poole");
    int larr = Integer.valueOf("Lawrence Sonntag");
    int james = Integer.valueOf("James Willems");
    int matt = Integer.valueOf("Matt Peake");

    Random r = new Random();
    int num[] = { adam, bruce, joel, spoole, larr, james, matt };

   }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the `int` value of "Adam Kovic" should be?

Comment: "Adam Kovic" isn't a number, is it? May be you mean Integer.getInteger() which return value from system properties?

Comment: use String and String array

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @dmitrievanthony Does integer.getInteger cast a string to an int

Comment: @AndersonVieira How would I set the int value? Also all I'm trying to do is make a game where it randomly picks one of those names and the user has to guess it until he/she gets it right.

Comment: ***What are you even doing?***  These conversions to integer make absolutely no sense.  [The documentation even states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) that this method is meant to be converting strings that are numerals into actual ints.  What do you expect a proper name to be the number of?

Comment: Okay, so you're attempting to make a collection of those, have a user enter a random number, and see if the collection at that number matches the name? Could you add those details into the question?  I've preemptively retracted a close vote since now your question makes a *little* more sense.

Comment: @Makoto I changed the "getValueOf" to "getInteger" also all I'm trying to is make a game where it randomly picks one of those names and the user has to guess it until he/she gets it right.

Comment: Okay.  Edit those details into your **question**.  Just by looking at this question it's completely unclear as to what you're attempting to do.  Be clear and be explicit about what you're asking.

Comment: BTW: you could use a enumeration here, especially if the list of names is fixed and you want to give them well known numbers/positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get away with just making an array of strings, each element being a string with one of those names, and have a randomized pick between 0 and 6; whichever number it picked would be the specific array element chosen.  Then in the code for checking if the player has picked the correct name, simply compare the user's input string to the string array element the randomizer picked.

Comment: How would I set a String to equal a number 0-6?

Answer (score 0):

Because Integer.valueOf() expects a number in string format. example "23".
So it should used in this case Integer.valuOf("23")

Answer (score 0):

Is this for your homework?

```
public static void main(String eth[]) {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("Adam Kovic");
    names.add("Adam Kovic 2");
    names.add("Adam Kovic 3");
    names.add("Adam Kovic 4");
    names.add("Adam Kovic 5");

    Random r = new Random();

    String name = names.get(r.nextInt(names.size()));

    boolean guessed = false;
    while (!guessed) {
        // guess, you can figure out how to get the guess
        String guess = "";
        //
        if (guess.equals(name)) {
            System.out.println("you guessed correctly!");
            guessed = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong! " + guess + " is incorrect");
        }
    }

}
```